# Countability and plural of buuz

Tags: plural-forms, countability

Is buuz (Mongolian dumplings) a countable noun, or uncountable noun? If the former, how do you pluralise it?

I tried looking up the term in onelook.com and only got a hit for Wikipedia, not for any dictionaries.

Comment: This needs an English usage/dictionary reference, otherwise this question is not about learning English.

Comment: @user3169 what needs an English usage/dictionary reference? That "buuz" is a word used in English?

Comment: An example in an English language context. Otherwise I expect it to follow the same rule as "dumplings". You might also explain why it could be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are **countable** though I tend to lose count when eating them!

***бууз*** (*buuz*, dumplings) is the plural for ***банш*** (*bansh*, dumpling), and appears to be irregular not using ***-гууд*** or ***-нууд*** to form the plural.

My guess is **банш** at one point was pluralised to **баншнууд** which then became shortened to **бууз** because the ***en-sh-en*** (ншн) is difficult and which also contributed to the change from ***de*** (д) to ***ze*** (з) at the end.

Comment: Although cognate with the Chinese-derived baozi, buuz is derived from a Mongolian word, which is not pictographic.

Comment: How should I pluralise it?

Comment: **buuz** (бууз) is already the plural, **bansh** (банш) is the singular. My guess is **банш** at one point was pluralised as **баншнууд** which then became shortened to **бууз**

Comment: Sorry, you'd already fixed it when I asked!

Comment: You can see it in google translate, use English -> Mongolian, type in "dumplings", then delete the "s"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from reviewing more than a dozen Google entries, the plural of "buuz" is "buuz." The Wikipedia article you cited repeatedly refers to "buuz" as a plural noun. "Buuz" are mutton-filled Mongolian dumplings (although beef is sometimes used instead of mutton). To confirm this usage, you may have to ask someone at a Mongolian restaurant!